# Multi-label classification with missing labels

Tags: multiclass-classification, multilabel-classification, softmax

I have a neural network that generates a vector that represents the class probabilities. Since it is a multilabel classification problem, I'm supposed to train the network using sigmoid + binary cross-entropy to calculate class probabilities independently but I only have access to one correct class i.e. my target vector is a one-hot vector where the vector values has one for the correct class and zero everywhere else.

Currently, I'm training the network with softmax + cross-entropy but I was wondering if there is another way to train.